# If I delete my WhatsApp account, will my other devices continue to receive messages?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

If I delete my WhatsApp account, will my other devices with my account on keep receiving messages that were sent to me?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume NO, since it has already been deleted. You will most likely get an error in your other devices.